# Django - How to access the value of a variable in a view on urls.py?

Tags: django, django-urls

I need to access the value of a variable in urls.py, the variable is on a view.

This is the view:

```
class MyFacetedSearchView(SearchView):
    __name__ = 'MyFacetedSearchView'

    def extra_context(self):
        q_query_string = self.request.META

        extra = super(MyFacetedSearchView, self).extra_context()
        extra['request'] = self.request
        extra['facets'] = self.results.facet_counts()
        extra['number_results'] = self.results.count() # Adicionado p AL
        extra['q_query_string'] = q_query_string # Adicionado p AL
        return extra
```

I need to access the value of this variable(q_query_string) in urls.py. This variable is passed on the url, just like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/results/?q=this_is_the_value_that_i_need_to_access_in_urls_py
```

Can someone give me a clue?

Best Regards,

Comment: What do you mean, access it in urls.py?

Comment: I think he wants to determine the view to use based on the value of "q". This seems backwards to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access some variable from view without GET dict you can use import:

```
from project_name.app_name.views import q_query_string
```

Be careful! In you example variable get their value only after running method.

Answer (score 1):

You have this value in:

```
q_query_string = self.request.GET.get('q')
```

Comment: I cannot upvote this because it doesn't answer his question on "how to access the value in urls.py".  Though I would argue that your answer is what he SHOULD be doing. urls.py is to dispatch to a certain view based on the resource requested. It's the views job to deal with the query string.

Comment: in urls.py is impossible or very ugly